# Trying To Install Windows Services - What's Wrong With This Code?

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I create a Windows Service project in VS2010 that contains multiple services. I tried to cull together a way to install it without a complex installer. But, it seems to rollback and not work.

Here's Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool install = false, uninstall = false, console = false;
        WindowsServiceInstaller inst = new WindowsServiceInstaller();

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg)
                {
                    case "-i":
                    case "-install":
                        install = true;
                        break;
                    case "-u":
                    case "-uninstall":
                        uninstall = true;
                        break;
                    case "-c":
                    case "-console":
                        console = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("Argument not expected: " + arg);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (uninstall)
        {
            inst.InstallServices(false, args);
        }

        if (install)
        {
            inst.InstallServices(true, args);
        }

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            // scans Email table for outbound email jobs; uses multiple threads to lock and work on data in Email table
              new EmailLogScanner()

            // generates email digest of document status on secheduled basis; single thread
            , new EmailStatusDigester() 

            // keeps Fax table and third-party fax service accounts synchronized; uses a fixed nb of threads, one thread syncs one account at a time
            , new FaxSynchronizer()     
        };

        if (console)
        {

            foreach (IDebuggableService srv in ServicesToRun)
            {
                string[] strs = new string[] { String.Empty };
                srv.DebugStart(strs);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            foreach (IDebuggableService srv in ServicesToRun)
            {
                srv.DebugStop();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Service has exited.");
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's WindowsServiceInstaller.cs:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer 
{
    public WindowsServiceInstaller()
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.NetworkService;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
        Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);

        ServiceInstaller emailLogScannerInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        emailLogScannerInstaller.DisplayName = "Email Scanner";
        emailLogScannerInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        emailLogScannerInstaller.ServiceName = "EmailLogScanner"; // must match the ServiceBase ServiceName property
        emailLogScannerInstaller.Description = "Scan for and sends out pending emails in stack.";
        Installers.Add(emailLogScannerInstaller);

        ServiceInstaller emailStatusDigesterInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        emailStatusDigesterInstaller.DisplayName = "Status Digester";
        emailStatusDigesterInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        emailStatusDigesterInstaller.ServiceName = "EmailDigester";
        emailStatusDigesterInstaller.Description = "Prepares document status email digests.";
        Installers.Add(emailStatusDigesterInstaller);

        ServiceInstaller faxSynchronizerInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        faxSynchronizerInstaller.DisplayName = "Fax Synchronizer";
        faxSynchronizerInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        faxSynchronizerInstaller.ServiceName = "FaxSynchronizer";
        faxSynchronizerInstaller.Description = "Synchronizes database with external fax service(s).";
        Installers.Add(faxSynchronizerInstaller);           

    }

    public void InstallServices(bool doInstall, string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AssemblyInstaller aInstaller = new AssemblyInstaller(typeof(Program).Assembly, args))
            {
                IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
                aInstaller.UseNewContext = true;
                try
                {
                    if (doInstall)
                    {
                        aInstaller.Install(state);
                        aInstaller.Commit(state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        aInstaller.Uninstall(state);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        aInstaller.Rollback(state);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

The logged output (when I run `daemon.exe -i` in a command window, as admin) shows the text below. Also, I get the "cannot start service from the command line" dialog:

```
Installing assembly 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   i = 
   assemblypath = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.InstallLog
Installing service EmailLogScanner...
Service EmailLogScanner has been successfully installed.
Creating EventLog source EmailLogScanner in log Application...
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   i = 
   assemblypath = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.InstallLog
Restoring event log to previous state for source EmailLogScanner.
Service EmailLogScanner is being removed from the system...
Service EmailLogScanner was successfully removed from the system.
```

UPDATE: When I comment out the try...catch block around the 'aInstaller.Install(state)' line, I get a slightly different output:

```
Installing assembly 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   i =
   assemblypath = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Da
emon\bin\Release\Daemon.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\
bin\Release\Daemon.InstallLog
Installing service EmailLogScanner...
Creating EventLog source EmailLogScanner in log Application...
Source EmailLogScanner already exists on the local computer.
```

Is it because I already have Event Log sources setup? If so, how do I skip that step in the AssemblyInstaller? If not, wha? :)

Comment: And what did `The file is located at C:\Users\xxx\Documents\~Business\Projects\Daemon\bin\Release\Daemon.InstallLog` say?

Comment: Actually, the last block above is what is logged to the InstallLog file.

Comment: oh, well then isn't that the problem? "Source EmailLogScanner already exists on the local computer."?  Looks like perhaps you create the event source every time you install, but presumably uninstalling is not deleting the event source.  So on subsequent times it's failing to create it since it already exists.

Comment: Thanks, you made me notice what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this

```
if (EventLog.SourceExists("YourEventSourceName"))
    EventLog.DeleteEventSource("YourEventSourceName");
```

when service installation begins.

Comment: Actually, my issue was a variant of this. In the assembly I have three different services. In each service, I have code that created an EventSource in the ServiceBase constructor. Seems like ServiceInstaller does not check before it tries to create an EventSource, and thus the conflict. I moved the offending code to a different method such that I could create the source if the service was run via console.